# mouseleave is trigged when hovering the scrollbar in google chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I  have the following problem: when I move my mouse on the right scrollbar to scroll down the page then the mouseleave event is triggered.

If I hover the scrollbar in firefox then it doesn't trigger.

Any ideas how to fix this in google chrome? Anyone know if this is a bug or not???

```
$(window).mouseleave(function() {
alert("trigger");
});
```

Comment: i don't get it. is the problem now in firefox or chrome?

Comment: This problem is in Google Chrome